# Filtering of Query not working properly

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle

I am filtering my `gridview` on the basis of the query from the database using Oracle SQL.

My conditions are, IF I am selecting state as `Bihar` and Status_id = 4. IT shows me all the status_id = 4

> but it also shows me other states such as `maharashtra`, `punjab`. I want it to show only Bihar state data whose status_id is 4.

Below is my query

```
SELECT ENB.SAP_ID AS SAP_ID,CAND.CANDIDATEID AS CANDIDATE_ID,ENB.R4G_STATE AS STATE,ENB.SITE_TYPE AS SITE_TYPE,CAND.SITENAME AS SITE_NAME,
CAND.STATUS AS CANDIDATESTATUS ,ENB.SITEID AS SITEID,ENB.PRIORITY_SITE AS PRIORITYSITE,ENB.CIRCLE AS CIRCLE,    
 DECODE (VTS.STATUS_NAME, null, 'Fill Vendor Survey form', VTS.STATUS_NAME) AS STATUS_NAME,
ENB.LATITUDE, ENB.LONGITUDE, VTS.STATUS_ID,VT.VSAT_DETAIL_ID
FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB ENB
INNER JOIN R4G_OSP.CANDIDATE CAND ON ENB.SAP_ID = CAND.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT ON ENB.SAP_ID = VT.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS ON VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
WHERE ENB.SCOPE = 'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
AND ENB.SITEBACKHAUL = 'MW'
AND CAND.STATUS = 'Fill Vendor Survey Form'
AND UPPER(STATE) IN 
(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER('Bihar'),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS RFIELDS FROM DUAL
                                          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER('Bihar'), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
AND VT.STATUS_ID IS NULL OR VT.STATUS_ID = 4;
```

Comment: No Sample data and Expected data ?

Comment: @SudiptaMondal: what sample data you want. OUTPUT of the query u mean to say ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing some brackets.

```
SELECT ENB.SAP_ID AS SAP_ID,
CAND.CANDIDATEID AS CANDIDATE_ID,
ENB.R4G_STATE AS STATE,
ENB.SITE_TYPE AS SITE_TYPE,
CAND.SITENAME AS SITE_NAME,
CAND.STATUS AS CANDIDATESTATUS,
ENB.SITEID AS SITEID,
ENB.PRIORITY_SITE AS PRIORITYSITE,
ENB.CIRCLE AS CIRCLE,    
DECODE (VTS.STATUS_NAME, null, 'Fill Vendor Survey form', VTS.STATUS_NAME) AS STATUS_NAME,
ENB.LATITUDE, 
ENB.LONGITUDE, 
VTS.STATUS_ID,
VT.VSAT_DETAIL_ID
FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB ENB
INNER JOIN R4G_OSP.CANDIDATE CAND ON ENB.SAP_ID = CAND.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_MST_DETAIL VT ON ENB.SAP_ID = VT.SAP_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL_VSAT_STATUS_MST VTS ON VT.STATUS_ID = VTS.STATUS_ID
WHERE ENB.SCOPE = 'EnodeB-Connected_MW'
AND ENB.SITEBACKHAUL = 'MW'
AND CAND.STATUS = 'Fill Vendor Survey Form'
AND (UPPER(STATE) IN  (SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER('Bihar'),'[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS RFIELDS 
                       FROM DUAL
                       CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(UPPER('Bihar'), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
AND (VT.STATUS_ID IS NULL OR VT.STATUS_ID = 4));
```

Comment: getting error as `ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"`

Comment: try now, type in there

Comment: can u explain me why we need brackets for getting the correct filteration. any special reasons ?

Comment: without them it treats all of the where clauses individually so when it comes to the `OR VT.STATUS_ID = 4` it literally ignores all the previous ones and does that

Comment: ohh, got it now. one more thing here. can I ask if u dont mind ?